# convert concatenated date and time to datetime in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have a raw datetime which I then used substring to grab each characters to form a datetime. Now I want it to be converted to proper datetime so that if ever I add 8 hours in hours it will never show an output of 25 but instead it will show 1.

Here's my code for concatenating the raw data

**RAW DATA**

```
$datetime = "150205172701";
```

**MY CODE TO MAKE THE DATA ABOVE DATETIME**

```
$hour    = substr($datetime, 6, 2) + 8;
        $minutes = substr($datetime, 8, 2);
        $second  = substr($datetime, 10, 2);
        $year    = substr($datetime, 0, 2);
        $month   = substr($datetime, 2, 2);
        $day     = substr($datetime, 4, 2);
$findate = "20" .$year. "-" .$month. "-" .$day. " " .$hour. ":" .$minutes. ":" .$second. ".000";
```

RESULT WOULD BE
**2015-02-05 25:27:01.000**

EXPECTED RESULT
**2015-02-05 01:27:01.000**

Comment: why not using the date-function?

Comment: This seems like a really long way around of doing it - what is the original data you created the raw "datetime" out of?

Comment: You give the wrong position to hour substr

Comment: @Roi patrick Florentino The new answer i posted works have a look at it

Comment: Might be you want to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427683/convert-concatenated-date-and-time-to-datetime-in-php/28428609#28428609

Answer (score 1):

You are making this far too complicated. Take a look at the [\DateTime classes](http://php.net/datetime) and you will see that it can be as simple as:-

```
$datetime = "150205172701";
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('ymdHis', $datetime);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
```

Output:-

> 2015-02-05 17:27:01.000000

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/t5Ds2)

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetime = "150205172701";    
$php_timestamp_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datetime);
echo $php_timestamp_date;
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

try date_create_from_format method:

```
$findate = date_create_from_format ( "Y-m-d G:i:s" ,  "20" .$year. "-" .$month. "-" .$day. " " .$hour. ":" .$minutes. ":" .$second. ".000");
```

the format String specifies the desired output format of your dateTime

Y - 4 digits year
m - month in numbers with leading zeroes
d - day in numbers with leading zeroes
G - 24 hour time with leading zeroes
i - minutes with leading zeroes
s - seconds with leading zeroes
if you want to alter the format, check  http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below

```
<?php
$datetime = 150205172701;

        $minutes = substr($datetime, 8, 2);
        $second  = substr($datetime, 10, 2);
        $year    = substr($datetime, 0, 2);
        $month   = substr($datetime, 2, 2);
        $day     = substr($datetime, 4, 2);
$findate = "20" .$year. "-" .$month. "-" .$day. " " .$hour. ":" .$minutes. ":" .$second. ".000";
echo $findate; //2015-02-05 01:27:01.000
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: there's a missing hour and how did you add 8 hours to hours? result in mine is `2015-02-05 17:27:01.000`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this, take the date string you have built and add certain amount of time.

```
<?php
    $datetime = "150205172701";

    $hour    = substr($datetime, 6, 2);
    $minutes = substr($datetime, 8, 2);
    $second  = substr($datetime, 10, 2);
    $year    = substr($datetime, 0, 2);
    $month   = substr($datetime, 2, 2);
    $day     = substr($datetime, 4, 2);
    $findate = "20" .$year. "-" .$month. "-" .$day. " " .$hour. ":" .$minutes. ":" .$second. ".000";

    $date = new DateTime($findate);
    $date->add(new DateInterval('PT08H')); //this is where you will add the amount of time
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d G:i:s");
?>
```

This will output :

```
2015-02-06 1:27:01
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have to devide `hour` by 24 and will give `1` which is not preceding zero. So, I put condition for that `($hour<10)` then append zero.

```
$datetime = "150205172701";
$hour = floor((substr($datetime, 6, 2) + 8)/24);
$hour = ($hour<10)?"0".$hour : $hour;

//Your code as it is
$minutes = substr($datetime, 8, 2);
$second  = substr($datetime, 10, 2);
$year    = substr($datetime, 0, 2);
$month   = substr($datetime, 2, 2);
$day     = substr($datetime, 4, 2);
echo $findate = "20" .$year. "-" .$month. "-" .$day. " " .$hour. ":" .$minutes. ":" .$second. ".000";
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YKZgi3)**